# Библиотеки для простого легковесного GUI

Tags: c++, gui, ui, поиск-библиотек

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, кроссплатформенные библиотеки для создания простого пользовательского интерфейса: окно, кнопки, числовые инпуты и чекбоксы только нужны.

У меня есть консольное приложение, хочу сделать для него графический интерфейс, как можно проще и быстрее.

Знаю про `Qt`, но слишком сложно и тяжело (в смысле целый фреймворк) для моих целей.

Comment: Кроссплатформенность нужна?  (Кстати, вопросы о рекомендациях обычно закрываются)

Comment: @MBo да нужна. Я прочитал описание меток [tag:поиск-библиотек] и [tag:поиск-программ]

Comment: ать: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries
двать: https://philippegroarke.com/posts/2018/c++_ui_solutions/

Comment: @Croessmah спасибо за ссылки. Случайно не знаете, есть ли что-то подобное `DearImGui`, но не требующее дополнительного бекенда?

Comment: @Croessmah нашёл по второй ссылке https://github.com/Immediate-Mode-UI/Nuklear

Answer (score 5):

С помощью 2 ссылки участника [@Croessmah](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189960/croessmah) https://philippegroarke.com/posts/2018/c++_ui_solutions/ нашёл подходящие варианты:

- [Nuklear](https://github.com/Immediate-Mode-UI/Nuklear) - простая C-библиотека реализующая IMGUI, MIT
- [NanoGUI](https://github.com/mitsuba-renderer/nanogui) - C++17 коллбеки, простая интеграция с `CMake`, BSD
- [microui](https://github.com/rxi/microui) - минималистичная C-библиотека, реализующая IMGUI, MIT